# Проблема с расширением Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Делаю расширение, которое выполняет простейшую задачу найти элемент с классом "нг-скоп" и если в нем есть класс "три", то удалить его. Это все, но почему-то я никак не могу это сделать. В чем ошибка?
Расширение для хрома, для всех сайтов.

```
let item3 = $(".ng-scope");

if(item3.hasClass("three")){
  item3.removeClass("three");
}
```

Comment: А вы JQuery подключили? Зачем он вообще нужен в таком коде?

Comment: Подключил, я уже просто от безысходности брал рабочие примеры расширений и пытался под себя сделать, но работать не хочет, думаю проблема глобальнее и связана с изысками расширений

Comment: Банальное `console.log` выводит?